# AWK: increment a field based on values from previous line

Tags: bash, awk, sh, auto-increment

Given the following input for AWK:

```
10;20;20
8;41;41
15;52;52
```

How could I increase/decrease the values so that:

- $1 = remains unchanged
- $2 = $2 of previous line + $1 of previous line + 1
- $3 = $3 of previous line + $1 of previous line + 1

So the desired output would be:

```
10;20;20
8;31;31
15;40;40
```

I need to auto-increment and loop over the lines,
using associative arrays, but it's confusing for me.
Surely, this doesn't work as desired:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

BEGIN { FS = ";" }

{
print ln, st, of
ln=$1
st=$2 + ln + 1
of=$3 + ln + 1
}
```

Comment: Are you sure that you desired output is correct? I think it doesn't follow the logic which you mentioned, please check it once.

Comment: I'd say it is correct. Line1 doesn't have any previous line, so no changes there. Line2 needs to be changed based on Line1, so its two new values are `20 + 10 + 1 = 31`. Line3 needs to be changed based on Line2, so there the new values are `31 + 8 + 1 = 40`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with awk

```
awk -F";" -v OFS=";" 
    'NR!=1{ $2=a[2]+a[1]+1; $3=a[3]+a[1]+1 } { split($0,a,FS) } 1' file
```

split the line to an array and when processing the next line we can use the values stored.

test

```
10;20;20
8;31;31
15;40;40
```

Comment: Thanks, also for the explanation. Due to associative arrays, this is apparently not as easy to follow as @AkshayHedge's solution. But that's what I mentioned in my question, so I voted this as best answer.

Answer (score 1):

Following `awk` may help you in same.

```
awk -F";" '
FNR==1{
 val=$1;
 val1=$2;
 val2=$3;
 print;
 next
}
{
$2=val+val1+1;
$3=val+val2+1;
print;
val=$1;
val1=$2;
val2=$3;
}' OFS=";"   Input_file
```

For your given Input_file, output will be as follows.

```
10;20;20
8;31;31
15;40;40
```

Comment: I think this gives wrong output because of `FNR==1`and `$1`?

Comment: @marttt, Apologies, changed the code now, let me know if any queries.

Comment: Thanks @RavinderSingh, this is very nice to follow now.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'BEGIN{
           FS = OFS = ";"
     }
     FNR>1{
           $2 = p2 + p1 + 1 
           $3 = p3 + p1 + 1 
     }
     {
          p1=$1; p2=$2; p3=$3
     }1
    ' infile
```

Input:

```
$ cat infile
10;20;20
8;41;41
15;52;52
```

Output:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";"}FNR>1{$2=p2+p1+1; $3=p3+p1+1 }{p1=$1; p2=$2; p3=$3}1' infile
10;20;20
8;31;31
15;40;40
```

Or store only fields of your interest

```
awk -v myfields="2,3" '
    BEGIN{
        FS=OFS=";";
        split(myfields,t,/,/)
    }
    {
        for(i in t)
        {
            if(FNR>1)
            {
                $(t[i]) = a[t[i]] + a[1] + 1    
            }

            a[t[i]] = $(t[i])
        }
            a[1] = $1
    }1' infile
```

Comment: This is easiest to follow for me, probably because it doesn't include associative arrays (of which I spoke in my question :). I think that's what I'm going to use, and maybe try to shorten using `=+`, `++`  etc of awkspeak. Thanks!

Comment: using `split()`, at least in current context its not really  necessary to store unused fields in memory (  array ) and access it in next row, for example if you got say 100 fields, if you use `split($0, array)`  array will hold all 100 fields in memory, which you really not interested, so used variables

Comment: Oh, I'll take this into account as I have several similar tasks coming up. Thanks for explaining.

Comment: Btw, @AkshayHedge, what does the very last "1" mean? In the part `...; p3 = $3}1`?

Comment: @marttt you may also do like this, `awk  'BEGIN{FS=OFS=";";split("2,3",t,/,/)}FNR>1{for(i in t)$(t[i])= a[t[i]] + a[1] + 1}{split($0,a)}1' infile` , set list of fields of your interest in split in begin block

Comment: 1 at the end does default operation that is print current/record/row, print $0. To know how awk works try, awk '1' infile, which will print all records/lines, whereas awk '0' infile prints nothing. Any number other than zero is true, which triggers the default behavior.

Comment: @marttt: I made an edit, probably thats what you mean by associative arrays